# Unable to download en_core_web_trf for spacy

Tags: python, installation, spacy-3

I tried using this command.

python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf

GOT this

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CB00B84B20>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CB00B84B20>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

Then I downloaded the model file from
[text](https://github.com/MaciejPastuszak/spacy_en_core_web_trf)
and then installed it from the terminal but still did not work.

also, I am not able to open this link in Chrome
[text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json))

Answer (score 0):

Did you install spacy?

try

```
pip install spacy
import spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

or

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

worked fine for me

Comment: Yes, the problem is only with my laptop, I am not able to run this command but from other laptops, I can access the link and download the file.
I cannot even create a mongo DB instance.
I think somehow all my connections are blocked.
any idea on how to solve this

Comment: You may check your network connection or a firewall that may blocking the request