# ConnectTimeout Error while downloading spacy models

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I started using spacy (3.6.0) recently. I understand that I have to download pre-trained models every time I re-start my kernel. It worked well for a couple of times with

`!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`

Then it started giving me errors. A little bit of research helped me find an alternative:

`spacy.cli.download(model = 'en_core_web_lg')`

Even this is not working now.

`!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg --direct --sdist` is giving the following error:

> ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting [https://github.com/explosion/spacy->models/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-%3Emodels/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz)
> ERROR: Could not install requirement [https://github.com/explosion/spacy->models/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-%3Emodels/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz) because of HTTP error 404 >Client Error: Not Found for url: [https://github.com/explosion/spacy->models/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-%3Emodels/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/-en_core_web_lg.tar.gz) for URL >https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/-en_core_web_lg/->en_core_web_lg.tar.gz

When I run the alternative `spacy.cli.download(model = 'en_core_web_lg')`, I am getting the following message:

> ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max >retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by >ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B06FFB8850>, >'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or it is really my internet connection issue like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544393/unable-to-download-en-core-web-trf-for-spacy)? My internet connection seems fine but for this.

Comment: what is your pip version?

Comment: try to update your pip for latest version

Comment: I had pip version 22.3.1 earlier. Upgraded to 23.3.1.  This seems to be the latest version also. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems issue with github servers as workaround you can download it offline then download the wheel file locally from your pip.

Comment: you can get the link form [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.6.0/en_core_web_lg-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl) it's from spacy website.